# Equating coefficients

Tags: functions

Excuse me,i don't know how to deal with this problem,i try it for all time of last night,
this equation is on "Concrete Mathematics" page 200:

---

d(n) is the number of derangements.
e^z is the generatig function for the  sequence

### [image]

[image]

this is the equation:

[image]

i want to know how to equating coefficients of z^n and get the result:
[image]

**Thanks!**

Comment: I've voted to close this as off-topic, and I think math.stackexchange is more appropriate for this question.

Comment: thanks,i will go to stackexchange

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The coefficient of $z^n$ on the left is ${d(n)\over n!}$. One the right, remember $1/(1-z)=1+z+z^2+\cdots$, so we have $$(1+z+z^2+z^3+\cdots)({1\over0!}z^0-{1\over1!}z^1+{1\over2!}z^2-{1\over3!}z^3+\cdots)$$ and you get the coefficient of $z^n$ by multiplying the term with $z^{n-k}$ in the first bracket by the term with $z^k$ in the second bracket, and then summing over $k$, thus, $\sum_{k=0}^n{(-1)^k\over k!}$.